# How do I track Stormpath authentication session with Stripe status?

Tags: node.js, session, express, stripe-payments

I'm currently using express-stormpath for authentication with stormpath in my node.js application. I'm also using stripe. I'm attempting to figure out how to store sessions correctly. Here's what I plan to store in a user session:

```
session: {
  sp_user: { //stormpath user details }
  db_user: { //details from my DB }
  stripe_expiraton: '234253843923' // unix timestamp
}
```

So on login I'm planning to create a session for the user with a 7-day expiration. On every API call express middleware will check to see if the stripe expiration date has arrived. If it has, or if there is no expiration date that means we need to redirect the user to the payment page. Otherwise will assume everything is normal and paid up and carry on.

Should I be storing session information this way? I'm not super experienced with session management.

Answer (score 1):

What I'd recommend you do is store this information in your User Account's custom data store. Each Account in Stormpath lets you store any JSON information you want.

This is going to be a much better solution that storing your data in a session, as it might get wiped by the user at any time if it's only client-side.

Also: for Stripe, it doesn't really make sense to store a timestamp in most cases. The way you typically do billing is:

- Collect the user's billing information.
- Send it to Stripe using their JS APIs, you'll then get back a token.
- Send the token to your Express app.
- Use that token to create a Stripe Customer Object. This way you can bill the user in the future.
- Store the Stripe Customer ID in your Stormpath Custom Data, this way you know how to bill the user later on!

With the above flow, you can automatically bill the user when you need to, instead of redirecting them to the payment page all the time. This also means you don't need to worry about session expiration, etc., and only need to redirect the user to the payment page if their card is expired or no longer valid.

Here's how to do it inside of a route:

```
app.post('/blah', stormpath.loginRequired, function(req, res, next) {
  req.user.getCustomData(function(err, data) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    data.stripeCustomerId: 'xxx'
    data.save(function(err) {
      if (err) return next(err);
    });
  });
});
```

The above code will save your Stripe Customer ID inside your Stormpath account.

You can then retrieve this data at any time by saying:

```
req.user.getCustomData(function(err, data) {
  if (err) return next(err);
  data.stripeCustomerId; // this will be the value you've previously stored
});
```

Hope that helps =)